# the amplitude and phase of a complex number to present it in pole diagram, Nyquist and Nichols

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

i have this equation

```
T(jw)=((1-jw))/((jw)^2 (1+jw))
```

> $$T(jw)=\dfrac{1-jw}{(jw)^2 (1+jw)}$$

and i want to calculate the amplitude which i found like this

```
|T|= (√(1-w^2))/(w (√(1+w^2))
```

please tell me if it's correct.
and the phase; i did't know where to start it. so if you guys can help. 
ps: it keeps telling me to write more about the problem i have, but that basically it. so i don't know how to fill the question. LOL

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

You need review your solution and notice that
$$|ab|=|a||b|$$
and
$$\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|=\frac{|a|}{|b|}$$
then 
$$|(jw)^2|=|jw|^2=|j|^2|w|^2=|w|^2$$
also
$$|a\pm jb|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$